# Link Check Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperlink

I want to make sure there are at least 1 characters before the finial dot, then make sure sure there is atleast 2 characters after the final dot...

```
link_regex = /^.+\..+$/i;
```

Doesn't work like that, I thought the .+ would be greedy and grab everything up to the last final dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
link_regex = /^.+\.[^.]{2,}$/i;
```

`[^.]` is any non-period character; `{2,}` says "2 or more".

Comment: No. `.` does not need to be escaped when it is already within a character class `[]`.

Comment: Really?  Yep, just tried it, you are right.  I can't believe I didn't know that!

Comment: so ^.+ gets everything up the the \. then the [^.]{2,} checks for 2 or more non . characters?

Comment: It'd be kind of silly any other way - after all, what would be the point of typing `[.a]` if `.` meant "any character" even inside brackets? The `.` would already include anything else you could put in the character class, so it'd be more efficient to just write `.` without the brackets.

Comment: @Shane: Correct. You use the `[^.]` to make sure that the `\.` matches the last period (since the last period, by definiion, has no periods after it).

Answer (score 1):

Huh? It works, but not exactly what you said - it will accept one character before and *one* character after the last dot. You need `^.+\.[^.]{2,}$` for what you described.